# PHP - Create a folder and save an image to that folder? Then display that photo?

Tags: php, image, upload

This seems like a big question, and it is, but the majority is done but I'm lost in actually getting where I want to be.

I have the upload form ready and it works, it saves it to a folder named upload, but I need it to create a folder depending on the hotel name that is saved in my session. This is displayed on the page to tell users what session they are on. So now when they save I need it to create the folder named after it to save it to that directory. So here is the code for the HTML :

```
<span class="prettyFile">
                                    <form id="form" action="assets/php/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
                                        <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
                                          <div class="input-append">
                                            <div class="uneditable-input span3" style="margin-top: -3px;"><i class="icon-file fileupload-exists"></i> <span class="fileupload-preview"></span></div><span class="btn btn-file btn-success"><span class="fileupload-new">Upload File</span><span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span><input type="file" name="file" /></span><a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists btn-success" style="margin-top: -3px;" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
                                            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary fileupload-exists" value="Upload"><i class="icon-cloud-upload"></i> Upload</button>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </span>
```

And here is the PHP:

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 10000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
    if (file_exists("upload/". $_SESSION['curHotelName'] . "/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
        {
          echo "<script language='javascript'>\n";
          echo "alert('This file exists! Please select a different file.'); window.location.href='https://hotelmobidev.jvgames.com/profile';";
          echo "</script>\n";
        }
        else
        {
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
          "upload/". $_SESSION['curHotelName'] . "/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
          echo "<script language='javascript'>\n";
          echo "alert('Success!'); window.location.href='https://hotelmobidev.jvgames.com/profile';";
          echo "</script>\n";
        } 
?>
```

I'm still messing with it but if someone can bump me in the right direction that would be awesome! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create the directory before you can move files into it. You can use the file_exists function to check on the **directory** first and then create it of needed:

```
if (!file_exists('path/to/directory')) {
  mkdir('path/to/directory', 0777, true);
}
```

You may prefer other permissions.

Comment: I didn't even think about that haha, that is a step in the right direction. Now it is a matter of having it specify to the specific name of the session.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax can help you ;)
Make one script - for uploading
Second - for check file in the folder & if it exists - display it

p.s. you will not resolve this problem with php only
sorry for bad engl

Comment: I have jQuery working on the side with everything just it isn't effecting the uploading. But thanks! I gotta figure out the set up on that.